# contentWindow iframe crm 2016

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016

please find below the code where I am trying to access a Webresource. I am working on CRM 2016

var xyz= window.xyz|| {};

$("#WebResource").contentWindow.xyz.Scheduler.load();

Gives out "Unable to get property 'contentWindow' of undefined or null reference" message.

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't manipulate the DOM, it's unsupported.

Do this

`Xrm.Page.getControl("WebResource").getObject().contentWindow.[etc. etc.]`

Comment: Unable to get property 'getObject' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out; manipulating the DOM directly is unsupported. However, if you're doing this purely for debugging purposes from the F12 console you can prepend your calls to the Xrm object as follows:

```
var webResource = frames[0].Xrm.Page.getControl("WebResource_Name");
var content = webResource.getObject().contentWindow.document;
```

Note that the specific frame containing the form does move around sometimes depending on which form you're looking at so if frames[0] doesn't work, try frames[1] instead.