# How to access IFrame's content window from CRM 2016 form

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to access Iframe content window from crm 2016 form using the below syntax:

```
var Rkn= window.Rkn|| {};   
    $("#WebResource")[0].contentWindow.RKN.Scheduler.load();
```

But I am getting Unable to access content window error. I used the below alternative as well

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("#WebResource").getObject().contentWindow.RKN.Scheduler.load();
```

But I am getting Unable to access getObject or null reference error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220751/contentwindow-iframe-crm-2016

Answer (score 5):

The second way you're trying is correct and the supported way, except you shouldn't use the `#` (that's part of the JQuery selector for finding by id). You can look up the webresource name in the form designer like so:

[image]

So assuming your webresource name was `WebResource_MailingRecipients` you could access the contentWindow of the IFRAME via:

`Xrm.Page.getControl("WebResource_MailingRecipients").getObject().contentWindow`